# Getting a file from html input field with vaadin

Tags: html, liferay, vaadin

I have to use a HTML snippet to get an image from Android/iOS devices with

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" />
```

which is displayed in a Label:

```
Label label = new Label("<input type=\"file\" accept=\"image/*\" capture=\"camera\" />");
label.setContentMode(Label.CONTENT_XHTML);
```

Because I'm using Vaadin on Liferay I'm not sure how to obtain the Image since there is no POST submit

How am I able to get this image?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write custom Vaadin component which extends FormPanel. Thats not hard as it may sounds, just let Vaadin Widget creator generate classes for you and then replace auto-generated GWT component with the following code

```
public class CameraCaptureWidget extends FormPanel {
public CameraCaptureWidget() {

    setEncoding(FormPanel.ENCODING_MULTIPART);
    setMethod(FormPanel.METHOD_POST);


    FileUpload f = new FileUpload();
    this.add(f);
    f.getElement().setAttribute("accept", "image/*");
    f.getElement().setAttribute("capture", "camera");
    f.addChangeHandler(new ChangeHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onChange(ChangeEvent event)
    {
        submit();
    }
    });
}

}
```

You can also add button instead of adding ChangeHandler on FileUpload itself.

After you are done with that you need to handle submit() event in the Connector. Example:

```
    public CameraCaptureConnector() {

    getWidget().addSubmitHandler(new SubmitHandler()
    {

        @Override
        public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event)
        {
            Window.alert("Hello world");
        }
    });

}
```

You may also need to remove some unnecessary auto-generated methods.

This solution generates this HTML code in DOM:

```
<input capture="camera" accept="image/*" class="gwt-FileUpload" type="file">
```

Should you encounter trouble, please make sure you have read https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+a+simple+component